# SQL like statement with a subquery

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I am having some problems getting the following SQL string to work in ms access 2007:

```
SELECT Tbl_Send.HTMLBODY, Tbl_Archive.[Document Number]
FROM Tbl_Send, Tbl_Archive
WHERE ((Tbl_Archive.[Document Number]) Like "*(SELECT [HTMLBODY] FROM Tbl_Send)*");
```

I want it to return all the document numbers in `Tbl_Archive` that are present in the field `Tbl_Send.HTMLBODY`. This field is a memo field and can contain multiple document numbers in one entry. I have tried almost all joins and different wildcards, but I'm stuck. I keeps returning 0 entry's, while there should be over 900. Thank you.

**EDIT:** What strikes me as odd is the following, when a query returns empty, or at the end, it usually looks like this, which allows me to see that there is 1 record and I am able to filter (Record selecter):

[image]

When I run this particular query however, it looks like this: [image]

This query returns something which disables all the functions of the datasheet as well, which leads me to believe that there is not something wrong with the SQL, but perhaps the query, because the answer provided seems correct to me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT Tbl_Send.HTMLBODY, Tbl_Archive.[Document Number]
FROM Tbl_Send, Tbl_Archive
WHERE ((Tbl_Archive.[Document Number]) Like '*(SELECT [HTMLBODY] FROM Tbl_Send)*');
```

Comment: This one also returns 0 records, while I (For example) have got the following records: `101689000 - F177 -  - Sales order is blocked for delivery: Cust Instruct/Docs`  and `101689000`. This should return a record, since the `document number` is in the `HTMLBODY`.

Comment: Try using single quotes instead of double with like, updated the answer.

Comment: I have noticed something odd, and edited the OP, since both wildcards, and double/single quotes did not seem to work